# Vue - When I switch between 2 card tabs, tinyMCE disappears

Tags: vue.js, frontend, bootstrap-vue, tinymce-5

I have component with tinyMCE wrapped in `<tiny-mce-editor></tiny-mce-editor>` in Vue Bootstrap Card component. However if I switch to second tab and back, the editor leaves plain textarea. I have tried many possible solutions I've found over the internet, but any seems work. The thing is that the editor component must be universal so I am not really able to catch it at card level and destroying it every tab switch that occurs. How am I supposed to fix this behavior? I am using tinyMCE v5 and completely depressed.

Answer (score 0):

May try add
tinymce.remove("YourSelectorValue");
before tinymce initialization.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).